# Is it safe to provide a function pointer with a const argument as a function pointer with a nonconst argument?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235710/can-a-function-pointer-with-a-const-argument-be-used-as-a-function-pointer-with) that in C it must be safe (based on the answers)

And I was wondering if it is safe in C++ to do the same (based on answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127168/c-function-pass-non-const-argument-to-const-reference-parameter), it should be). I have attached my code which compiles to show exactly what I am trying to ask.

I have a function that has a function pointer as its argument. The argument is a function pointer with nonconst arguments but I supply that function with a pointer to a function with const arguments.

GCC did not complain about it and I think it should be safe but want to make sure I am not leaving any details.

```
typedef uint16_t (myFunction)(uint16_t);

uint16_t increment(const uint16_t input);
uint16_t callFunction(myFunction* function, const uint16_t input);



uint16_t increment(const uint16_t input)
{
    return input + 1;
}


uint16_t callFunction(myFunction* function, const uint16_t input)
{
    return (*function)(input);
}

void setup()
{
    callFunction(increment, 2);
  /* add setup code here */

}

void loop()
{

  /* add main program code here */

}
```

Comment: In C++ it is same, the topmost const volatile qualifiers affect only mutability of parameters inside function body.

Comment: I realized what you said above is correct, but if the args are "const int&" and "int&" then the compiler complain. If I look at reference as a pointer, I can understand why it won't work because the const refers to what the pointer points to and not the pointer itself.
Could you please verify my understanding so I can add it to my answer, thank you.

Comment: Topmost thing in int& is reference that is immutable by its nature and so can not be volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comment from Öö Tiib. I decided to make an answer but with some detail so that I can marke the  question as answered not wasting other users' time.

Based on the Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ (N4727) in section 16.1 Overloadable declarations

> 3.4 Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of const and/or volatile are equivalent. That is, the const and
>   volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when
>   determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.
>
> `typedef const int cInt;`
>
> `int f (int);`
>
> `int f (const int); // redeclaration of f(int)`
>
> `int f (int) { /* ... */ } // definition of f(int)`
>
> `int f (cInt) { /* ... */ } // error: redefinition of f(int)`
>
> Only the const and volatile type-specifiers at the outermost level of
>   the parameter type specification are ignored in this fashion; const
>   and volatile type-specifiers buried within a parameter type
>   specification are significant and can be used to distinguish
>   overloaded function declarations. In particular, for any type T,
>   “pointer to T”, “pointer to const T”, and “pointer to volatile T” are
>   considered distinct parameter types, as are “reference to T”,
>   “reference to const T”, and “reference to volatile T”.

Based on the description above it is concluded that there must not be any issue.